# Reading .xml.bz2 Into R from a URL

Tags: xml, r

I am currently trying to automate a weather grabbing process from Environment Canada.  The site of interest is located at:

http://dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/xml/20140515/12/WIND-SFC/raw/

I have attempted to use getURL, xmlTreeParse, bzfile and download.file however each one fails in a different way.

> download.file("http:/dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/xml/20140515/00/TMP-SFC/raw/2014051500_GEPS-NAEFS-RAW_ABBOTSFORD_BC_CA_TMP-SFC_000-384.xml.bz2",basename("http:/dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/xml/20140515/00/TMP-SFC/raw/2014051500_GEPS-NAEFS-RAW_ABBOTSFORD_BC_CA_TMP-SFC_000-384.xml.bz2"))
>
> Error in
>   download.file("http:/dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/xml/20140515/00/TMP-SFC/raw/2014051500_GEPS-NAEFS-RAW_ABBOTSFORD_BC_CA_TMP-SFC_000-384.xml.bz2",
>   :    unsupported URL scheme
>
> xmlTreeParse("http:/dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/xml/20140515/00/TMP-SFC/raw/2014051500_GEPS-NAEFS-RAW_ABBOTSFORD_BC_CA_TMP-SFC_000-384.xml.bz2")
>
> Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:
>   'http:/dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/xml/20140515/00/TMP-SFC/raw/2014051500_GEPS-NAEFS-RAW_ABBOTSFORD_BC_CA_TMP-SFC_000-384.xml.bz2'

Bzfile does produce an output however I have not been able to use that output to generate data. I have looked through many of the other questions regarding XML however, it seems many of the other individuals have these files on their local machine, which I would like to avoid. Further others were not dealing with bz2 xmls however I don't believe that, that is my issue.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: download.file just needed a second /, it would now access the file however it has an error saying permission denied. Would this be on my side or theirs?

Comment: Have a look at `RCurl` and it's friendly wrapper `httr`.  It knows how to decode a bunch of stuff.  Also, test your downloads using command-line `curl` first - this will tell you if the permissions problem in in R or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be on your side. I'm not getting any errors with:

```
 download.file("http://dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/xml/20140515/00/TMP-SFC/raw/2014051500_GEPS-NAEFS-RAW_ABBOTSFORD_BC_CA_TMP-SFC_000-384.xml.bz2", 
                  destfile="test")

trying URL 'http://dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/xml/20140515/00/TMP-SFC/raw/2014051500_GEPS-NAEFS-RAW_ABBOTSFORD_BC_CA_TMP-SFC_000-384.xml.bz2'
Content type 'application/x-bzip2' length 6370 bytes
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 6370 bytes
```